# Disable RSS for Wordpress 3.2.1

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I recently installed Wordpress (3.2.1) onto my server.  Prior to installing Wordpress, I already had a folder located at http://www.mydomain.com/feed  which contains various files and what not.

However, since I installed Wordpress, I have noticed that this directory is browsable and indexable.  Which means any "joe-schmoe" can browse through the directories and see my files.

I have tried disabling the feed by following the instructions on [this website](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/), but it didn't work.  (It just made my main domain webpage come up blank).

I also tried the [Disable RSS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-rss/) plugin as well.  And this did not work for 3.2.1.

Any other ideas so I can fix this issue?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Does the problem persist when you change themes, or does this only happen with your currently-selected theme?

Comment: Hi Matt, it persists with all themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  The plugin appears to work now.  The problem was not with Wordpress, but my configurations with Apache.  I went into cPanel and made the following changes [found here](http://www.techiecorner.com/106/how-to-disable-directory-browsing-using-htaccess-apache-web-server/), which worked.